# Executable without dynamic linkker

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, g++

Can I compile (using g++ compiler) an executable (on linux) and strip out the dynamic linker `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` ?
I mean that if I `ldd` the executable after building it should detect the linker of the current (linux) system.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I compile (using g++ compiler) an executable (on linux) and strip out the dynamic linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ? I mean that if I ldd the executable after building it should detect the linker of the current (linux) system.

It seems that the GNU linker option `--dynamic-linker` does exactly you ask for.

```
[ aquila tmp ] $ cat 1.c
int niam (int a) { return a * (a-1) ; }
int main(int argc) { return niam (argc) ; }
[ aquila tmp ] $ cc 1.c
[ aquila tmp ] $ ./a.out ; echo $?
0
[ aquila tmp ] $ ls /tmp/ld.so
ls: cannot access '/tmp/ld.so': No such file or directory
[ aquila tmp ] $ cc -Wl,--dynamic-linker,/tmp/ld.so 1.c
[ aquila tmp ] $ ./a.out
-bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
[ aquila tmp ] $ file ./a.out
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /tmp/ld.so
, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e520e119f419bf9b557da6d6b3158bb5ad2195e9, not stripped
[ aquila tmp ] $ ldd ./a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc775a8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa4901c7000)
        /tmp/ld.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556ec4bcb000)
[ aquila tmp ] $ ls -l a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ranga davfs2 8008 Apr  8 09:53 a.out
[ aquila tmp ] $ cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /tmp/ld.so
[ aquila tmp ] $ ./a.out
[ aquila tmp ] $ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd374a4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e87b9a000)
        /tmp/ld.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005595b5585000)
```

> I don't have /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, actually I don't have /lib64 path. My linker exists at another path. The problem exists when I want to deliver an output from my system to a system that has /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. So I was thinking if I can just strip out the dynamic linker path.

Note that
 - stripping away the dynamic linker path (the `PT_INTERP` ELF program header) with `--no-dynamic-linker` will create a binary object that fails to execute
 - the link succeeded even though the dynamic linker path specified in the link line was invalid at link time
 - while `ldd` shows the system dynamic linker, actually running the executable requires that the dynamic linker is present exactly at the specified path
 - (therefore) you need to know the path to the dynamic linker of the target system at link time

> it should detect the linker of the current (linux) system.

what is recorded there is the path of the dynamic loader, which is generally common across mutually compatible platforms (and compatible versions of dynamic loader). so it might help to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve and what is stopping you from it.

Comment: I don't have `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, actually I don't have `/lib64` path.
My linker exists at another path.
The problem exists when I want to deliver an output from my system to a system that has `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.
So I was thinking if I can just strip out the dynamic linker path.

Comment: perhaps you should read the `ld(1)` man page ; try the linker `--dynamic-linker` , `-rpath` and `-rpath-link` options. i guess you'll have to use the `-Xlinker` `gcc` option to pass them to the linker from the `gcc` command line.